# sql query to get the salary from past 3 years

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table salary that has salary details for an employee for various years like:

```
person_number           date_from         date_to           salary      RN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
272                     03-Mar-2022     31-dec-4712         109000      1
272                     05-Mar-2021     02-Mar-2022         100000      1
272                     10-Mar-2020     04-Mar-2020         100000      1
10                      10-Mar-2019     31-dec-4712         4678        1
```

I want to get the latest salary for past 2 years along with current year. I created the below query for the same -

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         person_number
         sal.salary_amount,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_number
                            ORDER BY date_to DESC) rn,
         sal.date_from
     FROM   
         cmp_salary sal
     WHERE  
         1 = 1
         AND TO_CHAR(sal.date_from, 'YYYY') = (SELECT TO_CHAR(Add_months(SYSDATE, -12), 'yyyy')
                                               FROM dual)
    )
WHERE
    rn = 1
```

Like this one above I have created a clause for all 3 years (just replaced the 12 with 24,36).

These separate query is returning the correct data for 2 years back i.e till 2020 but the only case it is not working in when the same salary exists in 2 years.

Eg- For person #10, the salary is the same from 2019, 2021 and 2022.

Because I am using the year comparison in my above query, it will not return an output for 2020, 2021 and 2022, because the `date_From` is in 2019. Ideally it should give me the same salary for 2020, 2021 and 2022.

How to tweak this? I have to create 3 separate queries for this.

Comment: Looks llike you want  year of date_to >=  year of (current date - 12 moths) in the inner select

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need 3 separate queries; one would suffice. Also, according to data you posted, there's only one row per year per person so it is a "fixed" 3 years back. Therefore, I'd think of something like this instead:

Sample data:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     cmp_salary (person_number,
  3                 date_from,
  4                 date_to,
  5                 salary_amount)
  6     AS
  7        (SELECT 272, DATE '2022-03-03', DATE '4712-12-31', 109000 FROM DUAL
  8         UNION ALL
  9         SELECT 272, DATE '2021-03-05', DATE '2022-03-02', 100000 FROM DUAL
 10         UNION ALL
 11         SELECT 272, DATE '2020-03-10', DATE '2020-03-04', 100000 FROM DUAL
 12         UNION ALL
 13         SELECT 10, DATE '2019-03-10', DATE '4712-12-31', 4678 FROM DUAL)
```

Query you might be interested in begins here:

```
 14    SELECT person_number, sal.salary_amount, sal.date_from
 15      FROM cmp_salary sal
 16           CROSS JOIN
 17           TABLE (CAST (MULTISET (    SELECT LEVEL
 18                                        FROM DUAL
 19                                  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3) AS SYS.odcinumberlist))
 20     WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM sal.date_from) =
 21           EXTRACT (YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - COLUMN_VALUE + 1
 22  ORDER BY person_number, date_from DESC;

PERSON_NUMBER SALARY_AMOUNT DATE_FROM
------------- ------------- ----------
          272        109000 03.03.2022
          272        100000 05.03.2021
          272        100000 10.03.2020

SQL>
```

Comment: also I didnt understand how this will work, what is column_value? how is it calculating the same for 2021 and 2020 ?